# How do I convert HTML superscript tags to PDF using Itextpdf XML Worker?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, superscript, xmlworker

I am using itextpdf version 5.5.6. I am pass the html containing superscript tag i.e. `<sup>ABC</sup>`along with other HTML content. But the text **ABC** appear as a normal text. Looks like superscript tag `<sup>` is escaped and **ABC** text appears as a normal text. Below is the code used for PDF generation using itextpdf.

```
CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory()); 
PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);                                                           
byte[] byte1=htmlBufferForPDF.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);    
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byte1);
p.parse(stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Any suggestions to solve this issue will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me with iTextSharp / XML Worker 5.5.11 [using the overloaded parseXHtml method](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/XMLWorkerHelper.html#parseXHtml-com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter-com.itextpdf.text.Document-java.io.InputStream-java.io.InputStream-) and explicitly setting the CSS style.

HTML:

```
string HTML = @"
<html><head>
<title>Test HTML</title>
</head><body>
<div>The 1<sup>st</sup> day of the month</div>
</body></html>
";
```

Parsing code:

```
string css = "sup { vertical-align: super; font-size: 0.8em; }";
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        using (var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTML)))
        {
            using (var cssStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)))
            {
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                    writer, document, htmlStream, cssStream
                );
            }
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(OUTPUT, stream.ToArray());
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in both HTML5 and PDF view.  It seems the pdf ignores the css but likes the tag...

```
<html>
    <head>
         <style>
            .sup {
            font-size: 60%;
            vertical-align: super; 
            }
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body><span>Something<sup><span class="sup">©</span></sup> Else</span>
    </body>
</html>
```